# angular-daterangepicker.js - Include in ranges list options "Single Date" option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, daterangepicker

I'm trying to create a new option similar with "Custom Range" option but to offer the possibility to choose only one date(like "Single Date Picke"r). So, this will make it full option and will cover all what I need. In other words, a new option under "Custom Range", named like "Single Date" will offer the possibility to show up one calendar in order to pick a date. This scenario can be done also using "Custom Range" but my requirements are to make this flow using only one calendar.

Please, knows someone a quick way to handle this feature? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I accomplished something similar.

A calendar directive that accepts multiple scope parameters.

```
showRange=boolean,
fromDate=dateObject,
toDate=dateObject
```

If the directive receives `true` for `showRange` an `ng-show` is triggered on a button that will display a date range when clicked.

In my `calendar-directive`, I have the HTML built out for both a single and range picker.

This way, if you are using the calendar directive in many areas, you can decide whether or not to show the `show-range` button by passing a boolean to the directive.

Comment: The only recommendation I would have if you take this route is to use ngIf instead of ngShow.  The difference being that ngIf conditionally adds and removes elements to/from the DOM, whereas ngShow adds both and conditionally shows/hides them via css.

Comment: I agree with @jme11, you don't need to write the button to the DOM.